# Positional argument is said to be missing but is given, what is wrong?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using `pygame` and have created a class called `Entity` and a Subclass `Player`. The class Entity requires an argument "pos", which is always just "pos", because the value for it is created in the init.

```
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, stype, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = stype
        try:
            self.image.fill(color)
        except:
            pass
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)

    def update(self, dt, events):
        pass

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, platforms, pos, *groups):
        super().__init__((pygame.image.load("lemon.png")), pos)
        self.vel = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))
        self.onGround = False
        self.platforms = platforms
        self.speed = 8
        self.jump_strength = 10
```

However when I try to run the code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pos'

Comment: `Entity.__init__` requires `color, stype, pos`. That's three things. You are only passing two things.

Comment: You are not passing any value for the parameter `color`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why only two arguments pass here:

```
super().__init__((pygame.image.load("lemon.png")), pos)
```

But the constructor of `Entity` requires at least 3:

```
def __init__(self, color, stype, pos, *groups)
```

I don't know your problem well, but this could be a solution:

```
super().__init__(color=None, stype=(pygame.image.load("lemon.png")), pos=pos)
```